# cordova emulate android error

Tags: android, cordova, ant

Hi I have just started on using cordova on windows and i have some problems with it.
When i ran `cordova emulate android` it kept giving me the error:

```
Error: Failed to run "ant -version", make sure you have ant installed and added
to your PATH.
    at C:\Users\HuiHui\Documents\BasicCalculator\platforms\android\cordova\lib\c
heck_reqs.js:43:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:652:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
Error: C:\Users\HuiHui\Documents\BasicCalculator\platforms\android\cordova\run.b
at: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\HuiHui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

And i have no idea what is wrong. 
I have installed `apache-ant` and added to PATH variable but it still gave me the same error.
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Can you run 'ant -version' manually from your terminal?

Comment: did you add the bin folder of apache-ant to the path?